# Difference between 打ち合わせ and 会議 and ミーティング

Tags: word-choice, business-japanese

What's the difference between 打ち合わせ and 会議 and ミーティング?

To me it seems that 会議 may be more formal, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Though this question has already been answered, if you understand enough Japanese, you can always look up words on Goo's thesaurus to try and get a feel for the differences between synonyms. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

打合せ is more generic.  When you go abroad to meet your boss, your colleagues or customers, you'd say 打合せ.

I use ミーティング for when I need to discuss a point with someone.  If you're a student and discuss with you advisor once a week, that's it.

会議 is defined as "there's a boring speaker, and everyone around is sleeping" :)
That's in fact a conference (even a small one with a handful of people).

Comment: +1 funny for the last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience:

- We use 打ち合わせ about going to a client's place, when talking internally.
- 会議 can be internal or external. 会議中 can be used internally or on the phone with clients.
- We use ミーティング for regular weekly section meetings where everyone tells what s/he is doing and what problems there are.

It might be specific to my company.

Answer (score 3):

For a business meeting: 会議

It basically means: "To meet for deliberations"

It's equivalent to the gairaigo: ミーティング (which I don't like much because there's a widely used Japanese term already)

[打ち合わせ](http://gogen-allguide.com/u/uchiawase.html) is used for meetings of people ”with a common interest". Meeting of a club maybe? As the link explains, it has it origins in Gagaku, where musical instruments need to "hit (taiko) as a unit and fit with the music"